# How to get internet access in a Windows 7 virtual machine

Tags: networking, windows-7, virtual-machines, internet, nat

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and have now set up two virtual machines in Virtual PC. One is the XP Mode machine which runs XP (obviously). When I set it's network connection to Shared Networking (NAT), it gets internet access without any problems.

On the windows 7 virtual machine, when enabling the Shared Networking (NAT) option, I get no internet access. It does however say that it is connected. Here are what the status says:

[image]

What can I do here? It works with the VM running XP. Why doesn't it work with the one running Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I actually found [a fix](http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/fix-virtual-pc-2007-shared-networking-nat-internet-not-working-in-windows-server-2003-2008-and-vista-guest-os/comment-page-1/).

I had to, in the VM running Windows 7, set the preferred DNS server of the network adapter to 192.168.131.254.

After doing that I can access internet in the VM. But, oh my, seriously? Is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: I just thought about adding a remark about the dns server (10.0.0.1 in your screen shot). It was just name resolution which didn't work. So you should have been able to browse the web using an IP-address in stead of a name.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that since it do work on the XP machine and since 10.0.0.1 is the router. But is this seriously how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Virtual PC is creating a virtual networking and NATing your VM's through the host. I'm assuming it creates that random 192.168.131.0 subnet to reduce collisions with more common home subnets. VBox does the sames.
You are expecting it to bridge, which will give you a "real" address on your internal network. VMWare does this by default. I don't know if you can configure VPC this way.

Comment: No, I wasn't really expecting it to bridge and get a "real" address. However I *did* expect it to be able to connect to the internet. So if Virtual PC are creating a virtual network, it should have created a virtual DNS server as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is connected to the network. Have you actually tried opening Internet Explorer? Maybe you have to configure a proxy server first?

Comment: Yes, I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".