# Not able to ping or tracert when using NAT on Virtual PC 2007

Tags: networking, nat, virtualization

I finally figured out how to get internet access on a Windows 7 guest running on Virtual PC 2007, as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/53639/how-to-get-internet-access-in-a-windows-7-virtual-machine/53644#53644). But one I don't get. I am not able to ping or tracert anything. Google.com for example. On the host I can both ping and tracert it. On the guest I can do it to neither of them. All I get is *Request timed out*. But I can visit google.com in IE.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using shared networking (NAT) rather than a direct connection.  Shared networking has the limitation of not being able to create ICMP packets (if you are not an administrator) which is what ping and tracert use.

[Here is a knowledge base article on it.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824508)

Comment: Hm, I guess that is the correct answer. Although I really don't like it :p (That it doesn't work that is). Tried to run the command prompt as administrator, but that didn't help anything...

Comment: Not the command prompt as admin, but all of Virtual PC.  When launching the app, right-click on it and select Run as... and choose Administrator.  You should be able to ping and use tracert.

Comment: 1.) The link doe snot work any more.
2.) How to run VPC as Admin (in win 7)? The start menu entry is just an explorer.exe folder and it does not run with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that ping isn't supported through the virtual network interface.

Another possibility is something weird with a software firewall.

Last you might need to run VPC as a user with proper access to the computer as [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/04/26/virtual-pc-shared-networking-and-the-problems-with-ping.aspx).